# How can I finetune XLM-R for neural machine translation between the same language(Catalan to Catalan-with different grammar structure))?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, sequence-to-sequence, machine-translation

Can I fine-tune XLM-R to do something similar to https://www.guru99.com/seq2seq-model.html
(encoder-decoder architecture or any other way that perform good in small dataset - around 1000)
For example:
Input: He sells food(in Catalan)
Output: Food he sells(in Catalan)